# Side menu with the search button on the Roku channel's home screen

Tags: search, roku, brightscript, scenegraph, side-menu

I'm developing a Roku application with SceneGraph and I would like to have a side menu with the search and other buttons on the channel's home screen.
I couldn't find how to implement this. Is it possible?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible by doing custom design. Left menu can be done using LabelList, proper tanslation should be given for other components in order to avoid overlapping of UI.

I have already done in 3 channels, so it's easy to keep if you have clear idea about the element placing.

Eg:

```
<Rectangle color="0x000000" width="230" height="440" translation="[-10,0]" >
  <LabelList id = "categoriesLabelList" translation="[5,20]" textHorizAlign="left" itemSize="[200,40]">
  </LabelList>
</Rectangle>
```

You can also hide the left menu when the indicator focus any other elements like RowList, MarkupList, Postergrid or any element. Showing and hiding should be handled in onkeyevent

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
end function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Jeswin Rebil please can you share a full example. I'm learning roku and need to implement the same thing.